# In Swift how can I navigate to another view controller without storyboards?

Tags: swift, navigation, push, viewcontroller

In Swift how can I navigate to another viewcontroller without storyboards ?

New to Swift - Objective C was a chore

Not using any storyboards

Have a manually created a tabbed application.

first tab is ReceiptsVC

- includes a table view
- includes a navigation bar with EDIT button for the table and a "new" button to go to "NewVC" the button calls the function newButtonAction2()

in viewdidload

```
let navigationBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRectMake(0, 20, self.view.frame.size.width, 44)) // Offset by 20 pixels vertically to take the status bar into account
    navigationBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    navigationBar.delegate = self;

    // Create a navigation item with a title
    let navigationItem = UINavigationItem()
    navigationItem.title = "Receipts"

    // create the "new" button
    var rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "New", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "newButtonAction2")

    // add table edit button to navigation bar
    navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem =  editButtonItem()
    // add new button to navigation bar
    navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = rightButton

    // Assign the navigation item to the navigation bar
    navigationBar.items = [navigationItem]

    // Make the navigation bar a subview of the current view controller
    self.view.addSubview(navigationBar)
```

...

```
func  newButtonAction2() {

    println( "newButtonAction2 firing ")



    //let vc = NewVC(nibName: "NewVC", bundle: nil)
    //navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    var vc = NewVC(nibName: "NewVC", bundle: nil)

    navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)

    println( "newButtonAction2 firing  FINISHED")

}
```

output is

newButtonAction2 firing 
newButtonAction2 firing  FINISHED
(the NewVC never appears)

I can "present" the view controller (modally) but I lose my tab bar

app delegate

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {


    let tabBarController = UITabBarController()
    //let myVC1 = TestViewController(nibName: "TestViewController", bundle: nil)
    let myVC1 = ReceiptsVC(nibName:  "ReceiptsVC", bundle: nil)
    let myVC2 = PieVC(nibName:  "DummyVC", bundle: nil)
    let myVC3 = PieVC(nibName:  "DummyVC", bundle: nil)
    let myVC4 = PieVC(nibName:  "DummyVC", bundle: nil)
    let myVC5 = PieVC(nibName:  "DummyVC", bundle: nil)
    let myVC6 = PieVC(nibName:  "DummyVC", bundle: nil)
    let controllers = [myVC1,myVC2,myVC3,myVC4,myVC5,myVC6]
    tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers
    window?.rootViewController = tabBarController
    let firstImage = UIImage(named: "Receipts25.png")
    let secondImage = UIImage(named: "Tab2.png")
    let Image3 = UIImage(named: "Tab3.png")
    let Image4 = UIImage(named: "Tab4.png")
    let Image5 = UIImage(named: "Tab5.png")
    let Image6 = UIImage(named: "Tab6.png")
    myVC1.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "Receipts", image: firstImage, tag: 1)
    myVC2.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "tab2", image: secondImage, tag:2)
    myVC3.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "tab3", image: Image3, tag:3)
    myVC4.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "tab4", image: Image4, tag:4)
    myVC5.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "tab5", image: Image5, tag:5)
    myVC6.tabBarItem = UITabBarItem(title: "tab6", image: Image6, tag:6)

  //   self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: tabBarController)

    // self.navigationController = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ReceiptsVC())
   // self.window!.rootViewController = self.navigationController



    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need navigation controllers for each view controllers in tabbarcontroller.

like

```
let myVC1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: ReceiptsVC(nibName:  "ReceiptsVC", bundle: nil))
```

Comment: Thank you very much -  I'll try it and come back!

Comment: In ReceiptsVC this turned my defined navigation bar area black. Have no doubt you are quite correct - but it won't work with my config.

Comment: a UINavigationController has it's own navigationBar.
and UIViewController has it’s own navigationItem.

try to use these instead of your custom navigation bar and navigationItem.

Answer (score 0):

In order to push a view controller onto a navigation stack, you have to have a navigation stack. The property `self.navigationController` is nil unless self is a view controller that is owned by a navigation controller.

This method call:

```
navigationController?.pushViewController(vc, animated: true)
```

All be skipped if navigationController is nil.

If you have a tab bar controller and each tab in the tab bar is supposed to have it's own navigation stack, you need to set up those tabs to point to navigation controllers that then contain a root view controller.

So you should modify all of your nibfiles so that each view controller you put in your tab bar is enclosed in a navigation controller.

It sounds like you're using nibfiles rather than storyboards? That's certainly easier than building your UI totally in code.

Comment: Thank you very much - I tried to embed the nib in a navigation controller - but it was "greyed out" from the drop down menu. Now that I know for sure what the problem is , I'll try to find  another way to do this.

Comment: I built a big tabbed project from code in Obj C - had so many troubles with IB/ auto-layout. This project is not nearly as big, with latest Swift and IB I had initial success. But had insurmountable problems with highly customized cell and IB created tableView. At this point I think I should probably go back to a tabbed app and start all over - perhaps hard code portions of the receipts menu.

Comment: IB is much better than doing your views in code. Storyboards are not a lot different than NIBs, but better overall. They take some getting used to though.

Comment: Thank you sir - tom.e.kid needed the accepted answer points a little more than you :-)  , but I truly appreciate your insight.    And yes the  previous project - all UI's done in code took a loooong time. Need to come to grips with IB